# Python 3.4: programmatically download standard library module wsgiref without using pip

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-import, bottle

I am using the Bottle micro-web framework within a closed python installation. The standard library of this python install is very limited. Unsurprisingly pip is not there so I can't import pip and go that route.

I can get Bottle to run when I pull wsgiref from a previously installed Python on my computer and copy it into the directory of my running script but that's not a working solution for anyone who wants to run my script. I need to be able to download wsgiref from a suitable source.

The closed python install comes from the The  Sims 4 PC game. This is a script called `my_web_app.py` that I wrote. `bottle.py` and the wsgiref directory are in the same folder as `my_web_app.py` which is in a folder called `my_web_mod` under `\Electronic Arts\The Sims 4\Mods`. The below code won't run without The Sims 4 but it's here for anyone to use in case they have the game and want to test.

```
import sims4.commands
import services

from bottle import route, run
import threading

@route('/siminfo')
def siminfo():
    sim_info = ''

    def logger(msg):
        nonlocal sim_info
        sim_info = msg
    services.active_sim_info().log_sim_info(logger)
    sim_info = sim_info.replace('<', '&lt;')
    sim_info = sim_info.replace('>', '&gt;')
    sim_info = sim_info.replace('\n', '<br/>')
    return sim_info

@route('/test')
def test():
    return "<b>Test!</b>"

t = threading.Thread(target=run, kwargs=dict(host='localhost', port=8080))
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

Comment: Can you do `python3 -m pip --version`? Because then you might be able to install packages though `python3 -m pip install package`.

Comment: I don't have an executable python. The python runtime is packaged as a Windows DLL.

Comment: Python and its standard library [are open source](https://docs.python.org/3/license.html), perhaps you could make your own copy of the package you need, and distribute it along with the app?

Comment: Yeah, what @Blckknght said. That may be your best or even only option. Even if you were to use `pip`, I'm not sure that the PyPI version of `wsgiref` is usable with Python 3.4. As for programmatically downloading stuff in general, does this custom Python have `urllib.request`? Could you maybe call out to the system `ftp` (via `os.system()` or `subprocess`)?

Comment: It has the `urllib.request` module. @Blckknght I totally agree with your solution but I'm worried in a years (possibly longer!) time I'll have an out-of-date copy of that module sitting on a hard-drive / online vcs. I'm assuming here that the wsgiref module gets a few updates every year or so.

Comment: I think the question is, how often does the embedded Python interpreter in the game get updated? If it is not changed, you probably don't need to change the package you're providing either.

Comment: @Blckknght I had a very busy year! I ended up doing what you said and distributing my software with the package I needed. I downloaded a copy of the Python runtime and copied it from there.Could you submit that as an answer so I can close this question? Edit: Just to add, I wrote a small script to fetch this package before distributing my software so that the latest version can be distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the sys.path from your script before importing anything. 
if wsgiref is next to your script it will might work

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
import bottle
#all the other cool stuff you do...
```